# How to carry over arguments to error handling in discord.py

Tags: python, error-handling, discord

I have a say command for my discord bot. The command works by asking for a channel and message. If the channel is left unfilled it will raise a `ChannelNotFound` error. I already handled that error but I want it to send the message in the channel the command was typed in if a `ChannelNotFound` is raised.

Here is the command and error handler.

```py
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel = None, *, message=None):
    if message is None:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Say command",
                              description="Say something through It's Ez in a certain channel",
                              color=discord.Color.blue())
        embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar)
        embed.set_footer(text="Why was this message prompted? It's because you left message unfilled.")
        embed.add_field(name="Format", value="%say <#channel or id> <message>")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await channel.send(message)

    await ctx.message.delete()
```

```py
@say.error
async def say_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, ChannelNotFound):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Say command",
                              description="Say something through It's Ez in a certain channel",
                              color=discord.Color.blue())
        embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar)
        embed.set_footer(text="Why was this message prompted? It's because you left channel unfilled.")
        embed.add_field(name="Format", value="%say <#channel or id> <message>")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way that you can carry the argument over to the error handler, but you can use a `try:` and `except:` statment.

Here's your code with a `try:` and `except:` statment:

```
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel = None, *, message=None):
    if message is None:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Say command",
                              description="Say something through It's Ez in a certain channel",
                              color=discord.Color.blue())
        embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar)
        embed.set_footer(text="Why was this message prompted? It's because you left message unfilled.")
        embed.add_field(name="Format", value="%say <#channel or id> <message>")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        try:
            await channel.send(message)
        except ChannelNotFound:
            await ctx.send("Channel not found!")
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: Discord doesn't handle it's errors like that. The error happens when it tries to find the channel when you type the command not when you try to send it to a channel.